# where is the enum declared from user input c#

Tags: c#, enums

I have two enums and I want to determine from user input(string), in which array is the enum with the same name from user input

```
    public enum LengthUnit
    {
        mm = -3,
        cm = -2,
        dm = -1,
        m = 0,
        km = 3
    }        

    public enum NumericUnit
    {
        b = 2,
        o = 8,
        d = 10,
        h = 16
    }
```

string input = "cm";

Comment: Where would cm3 be in them enums? I can only see cm-2 so it wouldn't be found anyway

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be only "cm"

Comment: Tell us what you have already tried and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Enum.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx) which will let you pass a string and the enum type as parameters and an out parameter as the result if the TryParse succeeds.

Comment: Yes, but i dont want do "if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LengthUnit), input)" and "if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(NumericUnit), input), I ask you, if exist method, from which i get the name of Enum array, where is Enum which the same name...

Comment: You don't have to do that in the TryParse, it happens implicitly. You would just have to do something like if(Enum.TryParse<LengthUnit>(input, false, out myLengthUnit) || Enum.TryParse<NumericUnit>(input, false, out myNumericUnit)) {}